# how can I shorten a lot of if statement ? python

Tags: python

"this code aims to display a statement if the value of the lists (s,w) == 1. if not, it moves to the next index to check the condition and print its **unique statment**"

```
if(s[0]==1):
    print("you are a !")
if(s[1]==1):
    print("high !")
if(s[2]==1):
    print("jj")
if(s[3]==1):
    print("dkkdkd")
if(s[4]==1):
    print("kkkk")

if(w[0]==1):
    print("you are a low!")
if(w[1]==1):
    print("low !")
if(w[2]==1):
    print("jj")
if(w[3]==1):
    print("dkkdkd")
if(w[4]==1):
    print("kkkk")
```

Comment: Can there be multiple `1` in the lists?

Comment: Your question could use clarification. Also, make this a fully running script, including input, the output you get and the output you'd like.

Comment: The way your code is written, if there's more than one `1`, (eg. if `s = [1, 2, 1, 0]`) it will print more than one statement. Is this actually your intention? Do you know how to combine `if` with `else`? If you want us to make your code "shorter", you need to provide us with a _working code_, not one that _aims to do something_: you make us guess what you want and answers are likely not going to do what you actually want.

Comment: If a value is not a `1`, what can it be? Any number? 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
rtn_msgs = ["you are a!", "high !", "jj", "ddkk", "whatever"]

for i, msg in zip(s, rtn_msgs):
   if i:
     print(msg)
     break
```

Comment: how about `if i == 1:`, and no `break`. OP's code will print for all matches.

Comment: @tdelaney His question says "if not, it moves to the next index to check the condition", so I assumed he actually only wants to print the first match.

Comment: I think we'll have to wait for clarification from OP.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to trigger different actions depending on the value on each index:

One solution would be a for loop:

```
array = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]
texts = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5", "text6", "text7", "text8"]

for i in range(len(array)):
    if(array[i] == 1):
        print(texts[i])
```